# Couldn't able to retrieve google provider's user email address from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I followed the Firebase documentation to retrieve to a user's provider-specific profile information in manage users section of documentation.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
    // Id of the provider (ex: google.com)
    String providerId = profile.getProviderId();

    // UID specific to the provider
    String uid = profile.getUid();

    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
    String name = profile.getDisplayName();
    String email = profile.getEmail();
    Uri photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl();
};
```

I could able to fetch provider id, uid, DisplayName but I couldn't able to get email.

Below is `GoogleSignInOptions` code and `GoogleApiClient` with access to the Google Sign-In API code

```
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.gmaptest_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your project console -> Authentication -> Sign-In Method -> One account per email address (Prevent creation of multiple accounts with the same email address).
Delete created account, and sign in again,now you can get email address.

//I just wondering why you use 'user.getProviderData()', user.getEmail() is enough.

Comment: As per the Firebase documentation to get the user's provider-specific profile information I used getProviderData method, any how user.getEmail() is also working.